# function evaluation - I don't get it

Tags: functions, evaluation, scoping

this function returns Pi/4 for a[1,4]

```
In[...]:= a[r_, n_] := 
  Module[{an = Pi/n, h = r Cos[an], w = 2 r Sin[an]}, an];
a[1, 4]

Out[...]= Pi/4
```

so the kernel knows that an evaluates to Pi/4

This function returns something that seems inconsistent with how it worked before

```
In[...]:= a[r_, n_] := 
  Module[{an = Pi/n, h = r Cos[an], w = 2 r Sin[an]}, n/2 h w];
a[1, 4]

Out[...]= 4 Cos[an] Sin[an]
```

I get that Mathematica evaluation can seem non-intuitive but how this is as simple as it can get - comparing the 2 functions and their behaviors seems to show inconsistency: it knows that an=Pi/4, yet when `an` is used in simple algebraic expressions, `an` is returned unevaluated.

I must be missing something, but so far it eludes me.

EDIT:
after following user kglr's recommendation of reading the `Trace` I got the idea of moving the defn. of `an` outside of `Module` - that "fixes" things and gives me an actual answer but I am not yet quite sure why.

Comment: inspect `Trace[a[1, 4]]` to see how `an` is processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a module, the local-variable declarations aren't executed one after the other, but rather independently. If you want to execute code sequentially, put it inside the module, not in the variable declaration:

```
a[r_, n_] := Module[{an, h, w},
  an = Pi/n;
  h = r Cos[an];
  w = 2 r Sin[an];
  n/2 h w];
a[1, 4]
(*    2    *)
```